# nodejs exec cannot process start with quoted parameter

Tags: node.js, cmd

So I have quite a simple scenario. I want to initiate opening a docx file from my script. If I try to exec start without quoting the path, it works for paths without spaces but of course fails for paths with spaces. If I try quoting it doesn't run either the file with spaces or without.

My command which works for path without spaces:

```
        exec('start ' + filePath + '');
```

.

My command which doesn't work for either path:

```
        exec('start "' + filePath + '"');
```

For some reason, the quoted version opens a shell with the path of the file as the name of the shell.

How does quoting the path change what happens?
Invoking the same command from powershell works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reason you really need to use the `start` command, then you need to include an additional pair of double quotes because the first quoted argument of the `start` command is handled as a window title.

```js
exec('start "" "' + filePath + '"');
```

But, without a precise requirement for the `start` command, this should open your `.docx` file

```js
exec('"' + filePath + '"');
```